# Twisted deferToThread, not working with Mock.patch()

Tags: python, twisted

I have 2 functions both wrapped with `@defer.inlineCallbacks` decorator.

For tests, I'm mocking various things, including the `save_to_db()` function.

## logic.py

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def save_to_db(obj):  # mocked for test.
    raise Exception('Oh Noe!')


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def create_contact():
    xero = yield get_xero_client()

    data = {
        # <contact info>
    }

    # Create a new contact
    response = yield deferToThread(xero.contacts.put, data)

    obj = {
        # some data extracted from response 
    }
    yield save_to_db(obj)
```

## tests.py

```
import mock

from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.trial import unittest

from .logic import create_contact


class TestContactCreation(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('logic.save_to_db')
    @mock.patch('logic.get_xero_client')
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def test_get_xero_client_is_called(self, mocked_xero_client, mocked_save_method):
        yield create_contact()
        mocked_get_xero_client.assert_called()
```

However when I run:

```
$ trial tests.TestContactCreation
```

`save_to_db()` is actually called and as expected its raises an Exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<file_path>/logic.py", line 93, in save_to_db
    raise Exception('Oh Noe!')

exceptions.Exception: Oh Noe!
```

And I'm not sure why! I tried to debug using `pdb`.

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

It looks like `save_to_db()` is mocked correctly before we use `deferToThread()`

```
(Pdb) save_to_db
<MagicMock name='save_to_db' id='4404276240'>
```

However after the line where I've used `deferToThread()`

```
(Pdb) save_to_db
<function save_to_db at 0x111c6f488>
```

`save_to_db()` is no longer mocked! Only way I can get around this is if I also mock `deferToThread()`

Is there a better option? Any tips will be appreciated. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue; the `@mock.patch(...)` decorator doesn't work (i.e., it doesn't actually mock the desired thing) when used in conjunction with the `@inlineCallbacks` decorator.

What did work for me was to mock via context manager:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def test_get_xero_client_is_called(self):
    with mock.patch('logic.save_to_db') as mocked_save_method, \
            mock.patch('logic.get_xero_client') as mocked_xero_client:
        yield create_contact()
        mocked_get_xero_client.assert_called()
```

Does that work for you?